# How to schedule a PS script in task scheduler which copies files from remote computer to local machine?

Tags: powershell, copy, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, remote-server

My requirement was to copy certain files from remote machine to the local machine and I have written mapped the folder to the local machine.I use the drive letter of the mapped folder and the script works fine. But when I schedule the task, it throws error that the drive doesn't exists or isn't mapped.

Please find the script below:

```
$destination = "D:\Script\"
$source = "T:\"
$datefolders = Get-ChildItem $source
$TodayString = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

foreach($folder in $datefolders)
{
    $foldername = $folder.ToString()
    if ($foldername -eq $TodayString)
    {
        $path1 = $source + $foldername + "\*\*.csv"
        Copy-Item -Path $path1 -Destination $destination -Force
        $allfiles = Get-ChildItem "D:\Script\"
        foreach($file in $allfiles)
        {    
            $filename = ([io.fileinfo]$file).basename
        $filepath = $destination + $file
        $connectorfolder = "D:\Script\" + $filename + "\"
            Move-Item -Path $filepath -Destination $connectorfolder -Force
        }
        break
    }
}
```

Please note that the script works fine when ran directly. Please help me on how I can provide the remote server details which is shown as "T:\" drive in my script.

The error I can see in Event viewer is given below:

```
Error Message = Could not find the drive 'T:\'. The drive might not be ready or might not be mapped.
```

Please help.

Regards,

Mitesh Agrawal

Comment: This error implies that you may have mapped the folder to T:\ (and then it works for you, but the user running the scheduled task is someone else. For that person, the mapping is invalid. Either make sure the user running the task has a T:\ mapping or -better yet- use the full UNC path (`\\server\share\folder`). As aside, use the `Join-Path` cmdlet instead of simple string concats like `$destination + $file` to make sure you don't miss out any backslashes in the paths.

Comment: @Theo I have given the complete UNC path but still the script isn't successful. Shall I use net use command?

Comment: Hi, @Theo, for example, if my server is "Server1" and the path where the files are available is "C:\SourceFolder\schedulereport", then what will be the UNC path for this? I am able to manually map the drive using the same credential but not able to use it with the script and gets error Drive isn't mapped.

Comment: The UNC path would then be '\\Server1\C$\SourceFolder\schedulereport'. However, this uses the administrative share name for the C-drive on Server1 and it is possible the user running the script has no permissions to use that. Might be better to share the `SourceFolder` as `Sources$` (name is up to you) on that server and give permissions to at least read from there. Then, the path would be '\\Server1\Sources$'.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks a lot for your reply. I got the UNC path as "\\Server1\schedulereport$" but still I am observing Access Denied error.```Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At (Path for script).ps1:3 char:16
+ $datefolders = Get-ChildItem $source
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\srvmdc01\D$\M...schedulereport$:String) [Get-ChildItem], Unauthor
   edAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand```.

Comment: Can this be related to CredSSP, maybe the credentials aren't delegated or something?

Comment: If you have shared that folder as `schedulereport$`, you should use `\\srvmdc\schedulereport$`. Now you are also adding in the `D$` administrative share.

Comment: Don;t use d$ unless oyu genuinely have access to the administrative share.